# Sidekiq where is the job located right after being set using delay extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I'm scheduling a job with Sidekiq and want to check the queue size right after I schedule it:

```rb
MyClass.delay.my_method
Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new.size # => 0
Sidekiq::Queue.new.size # => 0
```

And I'm surprised that the queue is empty, though I see in the monitoring UI that the job was not yet executed (and in fact it gets executed moments later).

My real case is a bit more complex. I schedule a job and then render a page, and on that page I have a check if jobs of certain type are scheduled or running, but that all seems to happen to fast and my check fails (if I reload the page right away then the check succeeds).

I'm guessing there is a tiny delay between calling delay and the job actually ending up on any of the queues. Is there a way I can go around this, i.e. to check for all such jobs (that haven't yet landed on the queue).

Answer (score 1):

Delay just means "run this method in Sidekiq".  It is exactly like calling perform_async and the job will be enqueued immediately.

The ScheduledSet is for `delay_for(1.hour, ...)`, just like `perform_in(1.hour, ...)`, where you are creating a job and don't want it enqueued for some amount of time.

You are seeing an empty queue because Sidekiq picks up the job and executes it within microseconds.  A running job is no longer enqueued.

Comment: OK, so a running job is no longer enqueued, so then it should be available on the `Sidekiq::Workers.new`, right? However that size is 0 as well, while the job actually takes 2 seconds to finish. And I did confirm (by logging timestamps) that job indeed started (and ~200 ms passed) by the time I call the `Sidekiq::Workers.new.size`.

Comment: Worker data updates every 5 seconds https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#workers It's probable it never even got into the worker data if it started and finished within 2 seconds.

Comment: So, in other words, there is no solution. No way I can find my job moments after it was started? :(